# Spring Boot Actuator + Spring Boot Admin - Is there a way to define a custom management url?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Is there a way I can define the port for the management URLs (not the management.server.port) so that spring boot admin can identify the actuator URLs from the spring boot app for monitoring?
I'm running the spring boot app in a docker container and it's externally exposed on a different port using the Kubernetes NodePort.

Comment: Why is the question tagged [tag:netflix-eureka] ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using service discovery for application lookup you could define the exposed management port in instance metadata. This metadata is used to build up the management URL.
More details documented here:

http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#spring-cloud-discovery-support

Handling is done in `de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.cloud.discovery.DefaultServiceInstanceConverter`

Example for Eureka:
`eureka.instance.metadata-map.management.port=[K8S-EXPOSED-PORT]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Service Discovery, take a look into `DefaultServiceInstanceConverter`, try specifying the `management.port` property. 
If you are not using Service Discovery, then take a look into `de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.values.Registration`, you might need to use the builder apis to register your application correctly (try to set `managementUrl` properly). Note, you will need to do this in your client application (the one which is being monitored).